Missing link contents when exporting urdf from webots
I have a simple arm-on-a-shoulder robot in webots:
#VRML_SIM R2023b utf8

EXTERNPROTO "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/cyberbotics/webots/R2023b/projects/objects/backgrounds/protos/TexturedBackground.proto"
EXTERNPROTO "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/cyberbotics/webots/R2023b/projects/objects/backgrounds/protos/TexturedBackgroundLight.proto"
EXTERNPROTO "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/cyberbotics/webots/R2023b/projects/objects/floors/protos/RectangleArena.proto"
EXTERNPROTO "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/cyberbotics/webots/R2023b/projects/objects/kitchen/breakfast/protos/BiscuitBox.proto"
EXTERNPROTO "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/cyberbotics/webots/R2023b/projects/objects/balls/protos/Ball.proto"

WorldInfo {
}
Viewpoint {
  orientation -0.17401367641144078 0.07468296635017918 0.981907172271856 2.3439507669636304
  position 0.703091112289842 -0.48032550876184726 0.49198155824099044
}
TexturedBackground {
}
TexturedBackgroundLight {
}
RectangleArena {
}
Ball {
  translation 0.2 0.15 0.0325
  mass 0.01
  linearDamping 0.01
  angularDamping 0.01
}
Robot {
  translation 0.1 0 0.03
  children [
    Solid {
      children [
        HingeJoint {
          jointParameters HingeJointParameters {
            axis 0 0 1
          }
          device [
            RotationalMotor {
              name "mymotor"
            }
          ]
          endPoint Solid {
            translation 0.12 0 0
            children [
              Shape {
                appearance PBRAppearance {
                }
                geometry DEF arm Box {
                  size 0.2 0.05 0.05
                }
              }
            ]
            name "arm"
            boundingObject USE arm
            physics Physics {
              mass 0.01
              damping Damping {
              }
            }
          }
        }
        DEF shoulder Shape {
          appearance PBRAppearance {
          }
          geometry Cylinder {
            height 0.05
            radius 0.02
          }
        }
      ]
      name "shoulder"
      boundingObject USE shoulder
      physics Physics {
        mass 0.1
        centerOfMass [
          0 0 0
        ]
      }
    }
  ]
  physics Physics {
  }
  controller "my_controller"
}
BiscuitBox {
  translation 0 -4.77516e-07 0.13
  rotation 1 0 0 1.5708
}

When I right-click on it and export as urdf, the robot is missing the second part:
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<robot name="/home/nawal/data/software-exercises/webots/simple-actuator-for-mujoco/urdfs/Robot.urdf" xmlns:xacro="http://ros.org/wiki/xacro">
  <link name="base_link">
  </link>
  <link name="shoulder">
    <visual>
      <geometry>
        <cylinder radius="0.02" length="0.05"/>
      </geometry>
    </visual>
    <collision>
      <geometry>
        <cylinder radius="0.02" length="0.05"/>
      </geometry>
    </collision>
  </link>
  <joint name="base_link_shoulder_joint" type="fixed">
    <parent link="base_link"/>
    <child link="shoulder"/>
    <origin xyz="0 0 0" rpy="0 0 0"/>
  </joint>
  <joint name="mymotor" type="continuous">
    <parent link="shoulder"/>
    <child link="arm"/>
    <axis xyz="0 0 1"/>
    <limit effort="10" velocity="10"/>
    <origin xyz="0 0 0" rpy="0 0 0"/>
  </joint>
  <link name="arm">
  </link>
</robot>



Any ideas why the contents of the second  is empty? Thanks!
